# Два объекта в форме

Tags: java, spring

Использую spring и в одной форме нужно заполнить два объекта и вернуть их на страницу

```
 <form:form method="post" action="registration" commandName="userinfo">
<table class="paddleft">
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="username"><spring:message code="label.userlogin"/></form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="username" cssClass="form-control" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
...........
```

а в контроллере пишу

```
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public String registraion (@ModelAttribute() Userinfo userinfo, @ModelAttribute() User user, Map<String, Object> map){
    map.put("user", new User());
    map.put("userinfo", new Userinfo());
    return "registration";
}
```

знаю только такой способ, но как я могу, отправить и вернуть два объекта, первый объект у меня это личные данные пользователя ,а второй объект это логин и пароль, при чем логин нужно чтобы он писал в два объекта. Как можно это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) можно сделать обертку

```
public class UserForm {

    @Valid 
    private User user;

    @Valid 
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    ...

}
```

прицепить этот объект к форме и потом уже распарсить

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleRegistration (@Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // ...
    }

    User user = userForm.getUser();
    UserInfo userInfo = userForm.getUserInfo();

    ...

}
```

2) возможно заработает такой вариант http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html

```
<form action="" method="post">

<spring:bind path="userInfo.username">
   <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}"><br />
        </spring:bind>

....

<spring:bind path="user.password">
   <input type="password" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}"><br />
        </spring:bind>

....

<input type="submit" value="DO IT"/>
</form>
```